# Nginx configuration for separated frontend and backend endpoints

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

help me please... I have expressjs backend and vuejs frontend. I need to configure the nginx.
backend started on 127.0.0.1:3000;
frontend 127.0.0.1:5173;

I have now:
502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.18.0

My config:
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
#########################################################################################################################

 upstream my-domain {
        server 127.0.0.1:5173;  # Vue.js frontend server
    }

    upstream api.my-domain {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;  # Node.js backend server
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name my-domain;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain/privkey.pem;

        root /home/start/vuejs/dist;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

            proxy_pass https://my-domain;  # Proxy to Vue.js frontend
        }
    }

    server {
        server_name api.my-domain;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header   Host            $http_host;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade         $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection      "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy   true;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_ssl_server_name on;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_pass         https://api.my-domain;  # Proxy to Node.js backend
        }

        listen 443 ssl;  # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.my-domain/fullchain.pem;  # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.my-domain/privkey.pem;  # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;  # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;  # managed by Certbot
    }
```

the servers are working:

sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 5173
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5173                :::*                    LISTEN      214545/node

sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 3000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      214504/node /home/i

server locallhost:5173 doesn't work too...

Comment: Should this perhaps be:

proxy_pass http: